# How could I fix error for Stored Procedure Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to solve this:

> - Create a stored procedure named insert_num_proc that will insert numbers into the FLOAT_SAMPLE table.
> - This procedure should have two parameters, one for each of the two columns in this table.
> - The procedure should check the float_id column to ensure there is no duplicate (as unique values are not enforced in this column). If
>     there is a duplicate float_id, then the row should not be inserted,
>     instead printing a message saying “Duplicate value in float_id”.

Below is my query. For the second query, I execute my stored procedure to see if it shows my application error message, and it is not working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_num_proc
(
float_id_param      float_sample.float_id%TYPE,
float_value_param   float_sample.float_value%TYPE)
AS
float_checker   float_sample.float_id%TYPE;
 BEGIN

SELECT float_id INTO float_checker FROM float_sample;

INSERT INTO float_sample (float_id, float_value) 
VALUES
(float_id_param, float_value_param);

 IF float_checker = float_id_param THEN
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Duplicate value is inserted.'); 
 END IF;

 END;
 /

  EXECUTE insert_num_proc(3,2);
```

Below is error message I  get

> Error report - ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested
>   number of rows ORA-06512: at "DL29232.INSERT_NUM_PROC", line 9
>   ORA-06512: at line 1
>   01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
>   *Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
>   *Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

Comment: What do you see when you run your code? We could guess, but it will be instructive for you to have a look for yourself.

Comment: *"it is not working"*.  Do you get any error message?  Logs?  What does it do that you are not expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `WHERE` clause to check if that id exists, so it returns  multiple rows which the single static variable `float_checker` cannot hold.

Another problem is that if you don't have an entry already in the table, your select statement will fail with `no_data_found` exception.

So, define your `float_checker` differently so that it will save the count.

Further, your `INSERT` should come after the `IF` condition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_num_proc (
     float_id_param      float_sample.float_id%TYPE,
     float_value_param   float_sample.float_value%TYPE
) AS
     float_checker   INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(*)
       INTO float_checker
     FROM float_sample  WHERE 
     float_id = float_id_param;  --where clause for the passed id.


     IF float_checker > 0
       THEN
          raise_application_error(-20001,'Duplicate value is inserted.');
     END IF;

     INSERT INTO float_sample (
          float_id,
          float_value
     ) VALUES (
          float_id_param,
          float_value_param
     );

END;
/
```

Since this is an exercise, it's ok to use this code. But, in a real time scenario, the 3rd requirement should be handled by a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the table.

Comment: Although the procedure does what is required perhaps the error message "Duplicate value **is inserted**." is not very smart because the record has not been inserted actually. Better raise something like "Duplicate values are not permitted"